# t.test in R. Hypothesis testing for one coefficient, but you have a multiple regression

Tags: r

I have a regression like this y = β0 + β1xi1 + β2xi2 + ui.
And I want to perform a two sided t test that β1=3, 5% confidence

So according to examples I've found, I think I should do something like this:
`t.test(y~x1, data=data, alternative=c("two.sided"), mu=3, conf.level=0.95, var.eq=F, paired=F)`

But I'm wondering, how does this take into account that the regression I'm doing includes both x1 and x2?  Surely the coefficient will be different when both are added so the first line of code is wrong.  But adding it in like this `t.test(y~x1+x2, data=data, alternative=c("two.sided"), mu=3, conf.level=0.95, var.eq=F, paired=F)` doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Depending on how you ran your regression, you may be able to use the function `anova()` from base R. The only argument you need is the regression results. For example, `fit <- lm(...)` followed by `anova(fit)`. I know you said students t-test, but ANOVA is the same test. Without going into the math or other details, you will get the same results if you run a t-test and then ANOVA with the same data. Since you have documented beta zero, beta one, beta two, etc., it doesn't seem like the t-test is the right way to go anyway because you have more than one independent variable.

Comment: If you don't need an exact p-value but only a decision like "is or is not significant on 5% level", then you can just get the confidence interval for β1 and check whether 3 is in between the upper and lower bounds. To do that: `confint(fitted.lm.model, level=0.95)`